# Зачем менять форматирование с табов на ``` при редактировании?

Tags: обсуждение, форматирование

Собственно https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/676583/3

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем прикол? Отображение никак не изменилось.

Comment: Конкретно эта правка по-моему немножко бессмысленная, но в целом апострофы как по мне удобнее

Comment: Если писать ответ в мобильной версии, там нет кнопки {}, которая автоматически сделает отступ в 4 пробела. И там удобнее апострофы использовать.

Comment: @КириллМалышев вопрос не столько о различии в использовании, сколько о конкретной правке с заменой.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ нет, вопрос не к автору правки, а вопрос о разнице между пробелами и апострофами

Comment: @lampa из текста вопроса это, честно говоря, совсем не очевидно.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Конечно, спрашивать в первую очередь надо у автора этой правки, но...

Моё мнение такое: любая правка поднимает вопрос в списке, а значит, он может получить новые просмотры, новые голоса и т.п. Имхо, это первичная причина. В данном случае, человек правит своё сообщение и имеет на это полное право (право править!), может быть ему приятнее смотреть на сырой markdown, где код не сдвинут вправо, а может это упростит копирование кода куда-то ещё.

При этом если бы такие правки делались участниками через очередь проверок, их, конечно же, стоило бы отклонить.

Так же стоит заметить, что формально сырая ревизия с апострофами весит меньше, чем с пробелами при двух и более строках кода. Но, наверное, это экономия на спичках, особенно при условии, что старая ревизия никуда не пропадает. Хотя для первой ревизии вполне может иметь смысл при этом, хоть и ничтожный.

Comment: Т.е. разницы между табами и апострофами нет и можно и так и сяк?

Comment: @lampa табов там нет, это пробелы. И разницы м/у пробелами и апострофами/тильдами с точки зрения визуального итогового восприятия нет, насколько я знаю, и насколько об этом указано в справке. Апострофы/тильды - это относительно новая фишка для оформления кода на SE.

Comment: После правки пост стал весить в полтора раза больше, потому что теперь в базе придётся хранить ещё одну версию поста :)

Comment: @andreymal поэтому я и указал, что смысл может быть только для первой ревизии. Если это можно назвать "смыслом", конечно :)

Comment: Главнное преимущество апострофы/тильды, это возможность быстро поправить подсветку кода, например, `~~~none`, если подсветка вообще не нужна.

Comment: @lampa: _"... можно и так и сяк..."_ Не совсем верно. Скорее так: _"Желательно, но необязательно"._

Comment: @0xdb Мне видится, что явное указание скорее полезно, когда есть несколько блоков на разных языках. Но в любом случае отключить язык можно и через `<!-- language: lang-none -->` или указать другой, отличный от того, который подхватится меткой из вопроса.

Comment: Еще при тройных апострофах можно указывать язык, для подсветки синтаксиса, типа `\`\`\`python`, это полезно при наличии блока кода нескольких языков или если в метке вопроса нет метки кода, который в блоке кода оборачиваете

Comment: @gil9red а в чём была необходимость правки всё-таки?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, я решил привести в порядок все свои ответы и использование \`\`\` вместо отступов пробелами является одним из правил. Например, тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/705067/revisions и отступы поменял, и добавил еще пример в функциональном стиле

Comment: @gil9red это какие-то собственные правила, я так понимаю? :)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, ага :)

Answer (score 1):

Форматирование тройными бэктиками (и аналогичное - скажем, три тильды) не вносит изменений в форматируемый текст/код. В то время как форматирование отступом - изменяет его.

Типичный пример - переформатирование требует добавления и удаления переводов строк (очень часто наблюдается при форматировании SQL-запросов, которые то запостят в одну строку, то, ещё хуже, после pretty print какой-то среды). И если на каждой строке поналеплено по 4 лишних пробела в начале - замаешься приводить в порядок.

Дополнительно - тройной бэктик позволяет явно указать тип кода. В случае же 4 пробелов однозначно приходится полагаться на автоопределение диалекта, увы, неидеальное.

Comment: Язык можно указать явно и без тильдо-апострофов. Это уже упоминалось в [комментарии](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11448/%d0%97%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8/11466#comment49103_11449).

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Да, есть такое... раньше пользовался - так за всё время так и не запомнил, как оно выглядит, каждый раз приходилось в справку лазить. Так что для меня он так и остался как Чеширский кот - вроде и должен быть, а нету, одна кривая ухмылка...